# Expo AuthSession only half-works ...will fetch code but will not redirect after it gets token

Tags: react-native, session, redirect, oauth, expo

Hello I'm building a test app in Expo and trying to get log into get back a token to use a Slack App on my workspace.  All to say, that I can do a single call to get the code to further authenticate with and get a token and this comes back to my app.  However, upon the second call to get my token, I see the token is generated, but I cannot get it redirected back to my app.

```
fetchTokenAuthA = async () => {
  const redirect_uri = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl()
  const responseA = await AuthSession.startAsync({
    authUrl:
      `https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?` +
      `&client_id=${client_id}` +
      `&scope=admin` +
      `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`
  })
  const code = responseA.params.code
  const responseB = await AuthSession.startAsync({
    authUrl:
      `https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?` +
      `&client_id=${client_id}` +
      `&client_secret=${client_secret}` +
      `&code=${encodeURIComponent(code)}` +
      `&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri)}`
  })
  this.setState({ responseB })
}
```

If I log responseA, I see get the object with the code needed to sent to the nest URL to get the token. So...

responseB fires off and pushes to the next slack auth site and then I see the reply with object from slack, which is a success on my screen, but I am stuck on slack's website.  If I go backwards or cancel, I get a status cancelled object.

Not sure how I return the object I get on the second AuthSession back.